# C# byte[,] to string array

Tags: c#

**Context**

- I look for an simple way to covert a 2D byte[,] array to an string array in C#.
- I found the function `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` for convertig byte[] to string.

**Question**

- But what to do for 2D byte[,] array to string array. The lenght of the byte[,] is every time different.

Comment: What are you converting it to a string for?

Comment: Please give an example

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't a `byte[][]` array?

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[,] bytes = new byte[,] { 
    { (byte)'H', (byte)'e', (byte)'l', (byte)'l', (byte)'o', (byte)'!' },
    { (byte)'W', (byte)'o', (byte)'r', (byte)'l', (byte)'d', (byte)0 }
};

string[] strings = new string[bytes.GetLength(0)];
for(var i = 0; i < bytes.GetLength(0); i++) {
    byte[] stringBytes = bytes.OfType<byte>()
        .Skip(i * bytes.GetLength(1))
        .Take(bytes.GetLength(1))
        .ToArray();
    strings[i] = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stringBytes);
}
```

[Test it online here](http://csharppad.com/gist/b58653fbfb09be05b4e4). However, if the type were `byte[][]` instead of `byte[,]`, things were a lot easier for you... Can you please clarify why you are using `byte[,]`?

---

Explanation: `GetLength(int dimension)` returns the length of the specified dimension - in this case, `GetLength(0)` is `2` (for two strings) and `GetLength(1)` is `6` (for a string length of 6). We allocate a string array large enough to hold all our strings. Then, for each single string (in the `for` loop), we first get all bytes that belong to that string. This is done using Linq: We convert the `byte[,]` array to a series of plain `byte`s (using `OfType`), then we `Skip` all the bytes that we've seen before and only `Take` as many `byte`s as we need. These `byte`s are then filled into the temporary array `stringBytes`, which is then decoded into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Jagged arrays are much easier, since you can just traverse the array containing arrays. For them you could just have done something like:

```
var stringArray = byteArrays
               .Select(innerArray => Encoding.UTF8.GetString(innerArray))
               .ToList();
```

But since that are not the case we need to come up with something different. Multidimensional arrays are more like an excel spreadsheet where each cell contains one character.

The problem with that is that each row has the exact same amount of bytes, while the strings might have smaller sizes. The most standard approach for that is to terminate the strings with NULL (0).

Here is my working sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //different sizes for each row.
        byte[,] arrays = new byte[2,40];
        arrays[0,0] = (byte)'A';
        arrays[0, 1] = (byte)'B';
        arrays[0, 2] = (byte)'C';
        arrays[0, 3] = (byte)'D';
        arrays[1, 0] = (byte)'E';
        arrays[1, 1] = (byte)'F';
        arrays[1, 2] = (byte)'G';
        arrays[1, 3] = (byte)'H';
        arrays[1, 4] = (byte)'I';

        List<string> stringArray = new List<string>();
        List<byte> stringBytes = new List<byte>();
        for (int row = 0; row < arrays.GetLength(0); row += 1)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < arrays.GetLength(1); col += 1)
            {
                //got a null terminator
                if (arrays[row, col] == 0)
                {
                    //check if it's for UTF8 encoding.
                    if (arrays.GetLength(1) == col+1 || arrays[row,col+1] == 0)
                    {
                        //nope. End of this string.
                        stringArray.Add(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stringBytes.ToArray()));
                        stringBytes.Clear();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // add all bytes for the current row.
                stringBytes.Add(arrays[row, col]);
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in stringArray)
        {
            //prints:
            // ABCD
            // EFGHI
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

    }
}
```